# Firebase Analytics: Multiple setUserPropertyString (iOS, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

Trying to set 2 custom user properties asynchronously in Debug mode

```
FIRAnalytics.setUserPropertyString(value: "value_1", forName: "name_1")
FIRAnalytics.setUserPropertyString(value: "value_2", forName: "name_2")
```

No matter what the values are, I only see the last property updated in Firebase console debug view. So *"name_2" = "value_2"* in this case.

Can there be only one user property set at a time and should these requests be synchronous or is this just a debug reporting issue?

Couldn't find anything about this in Firebase documentation.

In Xcode console I see:

```
<Debug> [Firebase/Analytics]Setting user property. Name, value: name_1, value_1
<Debug> [Firebase/Analytics]User property set. Name, value: name_1, value_1
<Debug> [Firebase/Analytics]Setting user property. Name, value: name_2, value_2
<Debug> [Firebase/Analytics]User property set. Name, value: name_2, value_2
<Debug> [Firebase/Analytics]Engagement timer canceled
<Debug> [Firebase/Analytics]Engagement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 3600
<Debug> [Firebase/Analytics]Ignoring duplicate view controller
```

**Update 1**: If delaying a second request, both properties getting set correctly:

```
FIRAnalytics.setUserPropertyString(value: "value 1", forName: "name 1") 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
    FIRAnalytics.setUserPropertyString(value: "value 2", forName: "name 2") 
})
```

Just making it asynchronous without delay doesn't work though.
But documentation doesn't mention this is required and also the delay is arbitrary.

**Update 2**: The issue only occurs in Debug mode. The original code is able to set both properties simultaneously in production mode and notifications can be delivered accordingly.

**Update 3**: Contacted Firebase support, they recognized this could be an issue with data collection or representation in Debug mode and created a ticket to investigate and potentially fix the issue.

Comment: Just a comment to say I'm experiencing the same issue now, over a year later. Seems like the ticket they created wasn't picked up :(